# Constraint validation to not match a constant value

Tags: javascript, regex, html, validation

I'm trying to make a pattern-matching using `HTML5` constraint-validation to check if a value is **not equal** to a given value.

```
<select pattern="(?!ZZZ)">
    <option value="ZZZ">Please select a nation™</option>
    ...
    <option value="GER">Germany (GER)</option>
    ...
    <option value="ZIM">Zimbabwe (ZIM)</option>
</select>
```

In case the user has selected the default value `ZZZ` it should match and show the error-message (which is done via JavaScript).

I tried different online tools to check whatever pattern I use but nothing.

I simply need to check if the value does not match a constant string `ZZZ` but I don't get it.

Already tried to go the other way around so it has to match `ZZZ` and invert this regex somehow. But even there I get stuck.

Comment: I suspect if you can use `pattern` with `<select>`

Comment: @revo You're totally right. I'm such an idiot!

Comment: See [<select>](https://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_select_tag.cfm) docs, it does not support `pattern` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You're overthinking it. :-) Just make the value of that option `""` and use `required`:

```css
select:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select required>
    <option value="">Please select a nation™</option>
    <option value="GER">Germany (GER)</option>
    <option value="ZIM">Zimbabwe (ZIM)</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

From the WHAT-WG HTML spec for [`required`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-select-required):

> If a `select` element has a `required` attribute specified, does not have a `multiple` attribute specified, and has a display size of `1`; and if the value of the first `option` element in the `select` element's list of options (if any) is the empty string, and that `option` element's parent node is the `select` element (and not an `optgroup` element), then that `option` is the `select` element's placeholder label option.

And so selecting that option does not make the `select` valid.

Comment: I've also thought about this but needed the value `ZZZ` for later use so I swapped to use `pattern`. But as @revo pointed out `select` does ignore this attribute so I have to change it otherways

Comment: @KingKerosin: I assume you mean later use in JavaScript code. If so, you could always do this to get the select's value: `var value = theSelect.value || "ZZZ";` since `""` is falsy but no other string is. :-)

Comment: Yes, later in javascript, as there will be a select from a list of nation-objects I need to find the selected one by the value and pass this nation away.
But, as you already stated, this one I was overthinking and not checking the docs correctly ;)